# React Component not updating with state change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I currently have a reducer that does a deep copy of state and returns it with the updated value.

```
function countableItems(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case types.ADD_TO_SUM:
            let denomMap = findDenomination(state.denomGroups, action),
                nestedCopy = Immutable.fromJS(state);
            return nestedCopy.setIn(['denomGroups', denomMap.group, denomMap.key, denomMap.index, 'sum'], parseFloat(action.value)).toJS();
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

In my render function of the display Component I see the correct updated values in `this.props.denoms` The `render()` function builds up child `<DenomInput>` components, and when I set my breakpoints I see the correct data being passed in

```
render() {
    let denomGroups = this.props.denoms.map((denom, i) => {
        return (
            Object.keys(denom).map((key) => {
                let denoms = denom[key].map((item, i) => {
                    return <DenomInput denom={item} onDenomChange={this.onDenomChange} key={i}></DenomInput>
                });
                return (<div className="col"><h2>{key}</h2>{denoms}</div>)
            })
        );
    });

    return (
        <div className="countable-item-wrapper">
            <div className="row">
                {denomGroups}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

However when the `<DenomInput>` components render it renders the same value as what they were initially set

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class DenomInput extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { denom: props.denom }
        this.handleKeyUp = this.handleKeyUp.bind(this);
    }

    handleKeyUp = (e) => {
        this.props.onDenomChange(e.target.value, this.state.denom.name);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="input-group denom">
                <span className="input-group-addon">{this.state.denom.label}</span>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    onChange={this.handleKeyUp}
                    value={this.state.denom.sum} />

                <span className="input-group-addon">{this.state.denom.count | 0}</span>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

DenomInput.PropTypes = {
    denom: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    onDenomChange: PropTypes.function
}

export default DenomInput;
```

What piece am I missing to update the view with React and Redux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're seeding your initial state with the props from your store.  You then render from the component state, but you never update the component state. They only get set once because constructor is only called once the component is rendered.  To fix, either remove this component state entirely and just connect it to the redux store, or update the component state onChange.  I recommend removing the local state.  I have found that keeping the two states in sync is error-prone.

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { denom: props.denom }
        this.handleKeyUp = this.handleKeyUp.bind(this);
    }

    handleKeyUp = (e) => {
        this.props.onDenomChange(e.target.value, this.state.denom.name);
        this.setState({ denom: /*new state identitcal to change in redux store*/ })
    }
```

edit2: An example of raising state up. The steps are: 
1. Connect one of your parent components and grab the appropriate slice of state with a mapStateToProps function. 
2. Pass the props through your connected parent component to DenomInput.
4.  In this.denomsChange, dispatch the appropriate action. It is unclear what this is since you did not include your action in the post.

```
class DenomInput extends Component {
    ...
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="input-group denom">
                <span className="input-group-addon">{this.props.denom.label}</span>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    className="form-control"
                    onChange={this.handleKeyUp}
                    value={this.props.denom.sum} />

                <span className="input-group-addon">{this.props.denom.count | 0}</span>
            </div>
        );
    }
}


export default DenomInput;
```

Comment: The values look correct in `<CountableItem>` but not  `<DenomInput>`

Comment: what value goes in the comment? state.count.denomGroups?

Comment: I actually think you should try @PriyeshKumar's answer first, assuming you're correctly dispatching the actions that update your props. In general though, connecting is the way to go.

Comment: I didn't think you used those functions with Redux

Comment: Usually you don't have to. The problem is that you have both component state and redux state, and you're using your redux state, `props.denoms`, to populate your component state: `this.state = {denom: props.denom}` and then using the component state in your store. Since you never update the component state, you never see the changes in your component. I'll add an edit to my comment to show you what I believe is the more consistent/less error-prone option.

Comment: my goal is that <DenomInput> would be a dumb presentation component, so if removing one of the states is preferred, I'd like to learn that

Answer (score 6):

May be [componentWillReceiveProps](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) can do the trick. It will update the state of the component whenever new data is receive from parent, and  call the `render` function again.

Try

```
class DenomInput extends Component {
    ...

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
         this.setState({ denom: nextProps.denom })
    }
   ...
}
```

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps has been deprecated.

Comment: related post: https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html